# How to share memory between a GTK applications (or GTK and Console applications)?

Tags: c, memory, gtk, share

I'm trying to communicate two programs (in one I used GTK and in the other I used the Standard IO of C programing). In both I used shmget. shmat, ..., etc, to communicate them both.

However I'm having to much trouble to get the things done... Both programs do compile but none of them runs according my intentions.

What I'm really want to do is send data from the server to a client controlling the client program (in this test just printing the numbers on terminal), which will finish its execution after receives a signal from the server.

Unfortunately I couldn't made it with GTK but I almost did it in console application, however whem it is running automatic (without user interactivity) the Client crashes after 65516 iterations. In gaming programs this could be a problem, however for some applications the codes below will work satisfactorily.

My question is: Why an error occurs after reached 65516 interations (calls of shmat function on client program)?

In my future application this error have to be avoided or it will make the program crash...

How can I avoid it and keep my program (the client application) running indefinitely?

There are other ways to control a program through another program? which one is feasible or more practical?

File 
smh-02.h

```
#define  NOT_READY  -1
#define  FILLED     0
#define  TAKEN      1

struct Memory 
{
    int  status;
    int  data[4];
    int dado;     // I just add this data
};
```

File Console_server01.c

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/ipc.h>
#include  <sys/shm.h>

#include "shm-02.h"

#define RUN_WITH_USER   // Coment this line to user interactivity
                    // Or uncoment it to run automactic test indefinitely until segmented fail

 key_t          ShmKEY;
 int            ShmID;
 struct Memory  *ShmPTR;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
void send_data(int info)
{
while(ShmPTR->status != TAKEN);

 ShmPTR->status  = NOT_READY;
 ShmPTR->dado = info;
 ShmPTR->status = FILLED;   //Server has informed client that the shared memory have been FILLED    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

int info;

 ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x');
 ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Memory), IPC_CREAT | 0666);

 if (ShmID < 0) 
    { 
    printf("*** shmget error (server) ***\n");
    exit(1);    
    }

 ShmPTR = (struct Memory *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);

 if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) 
    { 
    printf("*** shmat error (server) ***\n");
    exit(1);     
    }

send_data(55); // This will send some signal to the client establish connection

    info = 1;           //----- Value to RUN_REPEATLY ------

    do
    {
#ifdef RUN_WITH_USER    //----------------------------------
    printf("\n Type:");
    printf("\n [1] To move to RIGHT");
    printf("\n [2] To move to LEFT");
    printf("\n [3] To move to QUIT");
    printf("\n You choice is: ");
    scanf("%d",&info);
#endif              //----------------------------------
    send_data(info);
    }
    while(info != 3);

     shmdt((void *) ShmPTR);         //Server has detached its shared memory...
     shmctl(ShmID, IPC_RMID, NULL); //Server has removed its shared memory...

return 0;
}
```

File Console_client01.c

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/ipc.h>
#include  <sys/shm.h>

#include "shm-02.h"

int  main(void)
{
key_t          ShmKEY;
 int            ShmID;
 struct Memory  *ShmPTR;
ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x');

int i = 0;  
int trigger = 0;    // trigger locked
ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Memory), 0666);

    if (ShmID < 0)
        {
          printf("*** shmget error (client) ***\n");
        exit (1); //Client exits
        }

    do{
        ShmPTR = (struct Memory *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);

        if ( (ShmPTR->status == FILLED)&&(trigger == 0) )
            {
            ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
            trigger = 1;    // trigger pulled
            }

            while (ShmPTR->status != FILLED)
                {
                printf("\nWaiting status = FILLED\t|\t");
                switch(ShmPTR->status)
                {
                case -1:
                    printf("Current status = NOT_READY");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    printf("Current status = FILLED");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("Current status = TAKEN");
                    break;
                }
                sleep(1); // Uncoment this line to better user interactivity
                }

        usleep(800);    // Uncoment this line to better user interactivity
        i++;
        printf("\ni = %d --/// | dado = %d ", i, ShmPTR->dado);

        if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) 
            {
            printf("*** shmat error (client) ***\n");
            exit(1);    //Client exits 
            }
        else
            {
            if (ShmPTR->dado == 55)
                {   
                printf("\nConnection ESTABLISHED"); //Go to the LEFT
                ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
                }

            if (ShmPTR->dado == 3)  // Exiting Program
                {
                ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;     //Client has informed server data have been taken...
                shmdt((void *) ShmPTR); //Client has detached its shared memory...
                exit (0); //Client exits 
                }

            if (ShmPTR->dado == 1)
                {   
                printf("\n<--- move LEFT"); //Go to the LEFT
                ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
                }

            if (ShmPTR->dado == 2)  
                {
                printf("\n---> move RIGHT");    // Go to the RIGHT
                ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
                }

            if ( (ShmPTR->dado != 1)||(ShmPTR->dado != 2) )
                {
                printf("\nIdle | dado = %d",ShmPTR->dado ); //Doing NOTHING
                ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
                }
            }

    }while (1); // 'Infinite' loop
 exit(0);
}
```

[Running the programs_Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtMDi.png)

[Error after 65516 interations_Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpM3P.png)

Comment: Could you reduce you issue space, it would be easier to get an answer, maybe start with [communicating with shared memory first](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node27.html) before trying to put it in a GTK/GUI application.

Comment: When you do what dvhh suggests, please take the time to also indent the code correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice dvhh and jku. I'd edit the code and the question, the result we can see above.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use shared memory for communication. It is not type safe and hard to code correctly.

What you truly need is serialization. Consider using [JSON-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) for communication. Yes, it is far slower than raw memory manipulation, but much safer, more portable and easier to make *just work*. [Some even use it for heavy and often loads, let alone occasional loads like GUI input.](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/red-hat-codenvy-and-microsoft-collaborate-language-server-protocol)